# Java Class - Array println

Tags: java, algorithm, class

i have 2 Class, the first class College and the second Lecturer.
in College class i have >> public Lecturer[] allLecturer;

I want the college department will receive the Lecturer department, But I have something strange when I try to print the college department.

class Lecturer:

```
public class Lecturer {
public String name;
public int numOfTimesPenFalls;
public String favoriteIceCream;
public int autoNumber;

//constructor
public Lecturer(String Name, int NumOfTimesPenFalls,
        String FavoriteIceCream, int AutoNumber) {
    this.name = Name;
    this.numOfTimesPenFalls = NumOfTimesPenFalls;
    this.favoriteIceCream = FavoriteIceCream;
    this.autoNumber = AutoNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "name: " +name+ " num Of Times Pen Falls: "+ numOfTimesPenFalls +
    " favorite Ice Cream: " + favoriteIceCream + " auto Number: " + autoNumber;
}
}
```

class College:

```
public class College {
public String name;
public int numOfLecturer;
public Lecturer[] allLecturer;
public int maxLecturer;

//constructor
public College(String Name, int NumOfLecturer, Lecturer[] AllLecturer, int MaxLecturer) {
    this.name = Name;
    this.numOfLecturer = NumOfLecturer;
    this.allLecturer = AllLecturer;
    this.maxLecturer = MaxLecturer;
}

public College(String Name){
    this.name = Name;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Name College: " +name+ " num Of Lecturer: " + numOfLecturer + 
    " all Lecturer: " + allLecturer + " max Lecturer " + maxLecturer ;
}
}
```

main:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Lecturer[] L1 = new Lecturer[] { new Lecturer("David", 3, "Banana",
            1001) };

    College myCollege = new College("College1", 20, L1, 10);

    System.out.println(myCollege.toString());

}
}
```

Result output:

```
Name College: College1 num Of Lecturer: 20 all Lecturer: [LLecturer;@139a55 max Lecturer 10
```

Why it prints me the ([LLecturer;@139a55) Instead the details of the department?

If I write in main for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < L1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(L1[i]);
    }
```

the Result output:

```
 name: David num Of Times Pen Falls: 3 favorite Ice Cream: Banana auto Number: 1001
```

How do I fix this so that when I print the class College `(System.out.println(myCollege.toString()) );`
I also printed the information that is in the lecturer Department?

thank you.

Comment: try this `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myCollege ));`

Comment: I'm trying to print as you noted and compile error

Answer (score 0):

hey when you concat an array with string it will use his toString function.
the default toString function will print something like you see in your code.
the toString of a single object in the array will print what you want .

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays do not override `Object`'s toString() method. just add the loop that you wrote to the toString() method of `College`

example solution:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Name College: " +name+ " num Of Lecturer: " + numOfLecturer + 
    " all Lecturer: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(allLecturer) + " max Lecturer " + maxLecturer ;
}
```

and if you can use 3rd party library, take a look at Apache's `StringUtils` class, it has a handy [`join()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Object[],%20char)) method that produces a String from concatanating array of objects

Comment: like this?                                                                                                                             public String toString(){
         Lecturer[]L1= new Lecturer[allLecturer.length];
                this.allLecturer = L1;
  for (int i = 0; i < L1.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(L1[i]);
  }
  return "Name College: " +name+ " num Of Lecturer: " + numOfLecturer + 
  " all Lecturer: " + allLecturer + " max Lecturer " + maxLecturer ;
 }

Comment: I wrote the same thing but I have a compile error under (Arrays)                                                                       in this row>> (Arrays.toString(allLecturer))

Answer (score 0):

change your `toString()` method in `College.java` to

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Name College: " +name+ " num Of Lecturer: " + numOfLecturer + 
    " all Lecturer: " + Arrays.toString(allLecturer) + " max Lecturer " + maxLecturer ;
}
```

and in your main method try to print your `College` reference

```
College myCollege = new College("College1", 20, L1, 10);
System.out.println(myCollege);
```

**now your output is:**

```
Name College: College1 num Of Lecturer: 20 all Lecturer: [name: David num Of Times Pen Falls: 3 favorite Ice Cream: Banana auto Number: 1001] max Lecturer 10
```

Comment: I have a compile error under (Arrays)                                                                       in this row>> (Arrays.toString(allLecturer))